# How can I add follower in .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new in ASP.NET MVC and I met with many-to-many at first time. I should to add current user to the followers of a found user and at the same time add user to following of current user.

Here is problem in saving of an entity of `User` in the database. Because in my function `Follow`, everything is going well and added to determined fields. But in when it skipped to function `Personal`, it returned null fields. I don't know where the problem is. Maybe someone before has asked a similar question, but I couldn't find a solution.

Here is code in context:

```
public Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<User> ContextUser { get; set; }
public Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
public Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
public Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<Like> Likes { get; set; }

protected void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasMany(x => x.Followers).WithMany(x => x.Following)
                .Map(x => x.ToTable("Followers")
                    .MapLeftKey("UserId")
                    .MapRightKey("FollowerId"));
}
```

Here is my entity `User`:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Nullable<bool> Gender { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Followers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Following { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the controller code:

```
public IActionResult Follow(string Id)
{
    var user = _db.ContextUser.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id);
    var currentUser = CurrentUser().Result;

    if (user.Followers == null)
    {
        user.Followers = new Collection<User>();
    }

    user.Followers.Add(currentUser);

    if (currentUser.Following == null)
    {
        currentUser.Following = new Collection<User>();
    }

    currentUser.Following.Add(user);

    var sub = new Subcribe
        {
            FollowedBy = user,
            User = currentUser
        };

    _db.Subcribes.Add(sub);
    _db.ContextUser.Update(user);
    _db.ContextUser.Update(currentUser);

    _db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Personal", "Post", new { Id = Id});
}

public IActionResult Personal(string Id)
{
    var user = _db.ContextUser.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == Id);
    var users = _db.ContextUser.ToList();
    //var followers = _db.ContextUser.Include(u => u.Following.Where(f => f.Id == Id)).ToList();
    //user.Followers = followers;
    //var following = _db.ContextUser.Include(u => u.Followers.Where(f => f.Id == Id)).ToList();
    //user.Following = following;

    var posts = _db.Posts.Where(p => p.UserId == Id);
    user.Posts = posts.ToList();

    return View(user);
}
```

Comment: I get what `Follow()` does, but what is `Personal()`?  Did you mean `GetUser()`?

Answer (score 0):

To keep many-to-many relations you need to add one more table and relations

```
public partial class FollowerFollowing 
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

         public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int? FollowingId { get; set; }
        public int? FollowerId{ get; set; }

         public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public virtual User Following  { get; set; }
        public virtual User Follower { get; set; }
    }
    public class User : IdentityUser
   {
    .......
    public ICollection<FollowerFollowing> FollowerFollowings { get; set; }

    public ICollection<FollowerFollowing> Followers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FollowerFollowing> Followings { get; set; }
  
   }
```

or a flag could be used that makes the table a little simplier

```
public partial class FollowerFollowing 
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

         public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int? FollowId { get; set; }

        public bool IsFollower{ get; set; }

         public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public virtual User Follow  { get; set; }
       
    }
```